# How to calculate exact streaming duration time in web?

Tags: javascript, streaming, audio-streaming, wowza, internet-radio

I am running streaming on wowza streaming server. But I am not able to find the exact duration time of streaming.

I am running music website on which we play streaming on user native player. For our tracking we want to keep track of exact time duration of the audio listen by the user.

Comment: I don't know wowza server, but do you have an audio tag in your page?
if so, you can acess to several datas about the audio file: duration, current time, ecc ecc

Comment: @OmarEnricoPolo..yes, I get some audio tags with api..such as - streaming duration, streaming link. But i want to know the exact time duration of the song listen by the user.

Comment: Are you developing a custom Wowza module? What is the context? Maybe take a look at [Wowza Wrench](http://wowzatoolbox.com/wrench)'s `wrench.disconnect.log.time.sql` feature, which allows you to execute a SQL and then you can log the time the user was listening to the music

Comment: @jabal..the user was listening the music in mobile native player.So, all th handle goes to the client side. I want to know the exact time duration of the audio listen by the user.

Comment: @RohitJindal Which transport protocol are you using for streaming, HTTP (eg. HLS, HDS, Smooth, DASH), or RTMP? In case of HTTP, it's going to be difficult to know the exact duration server side; I would definitely implement a client-side solution. You may also ask you question on http://www.wowza.com/forums/forum.php

Comment: @KBoek I am using rtsp(Real Time Streaming Protocol) for streaming. when user listen the music on its mobile native player the overall control goes to client side.So, we have to implement a client-side solution.please help me.

Comment: @RohitJindal What did you use to develop this Mobile Native Player?

Comment: @KBoek Mobile Native player open automatically when user click on the play button. we are just sending the streaming url on click the play button.

Comment: @RohitJindal I see. In that case you may need to develop a custom app that has a player and counter; I don't think it's possible to get the play duration from the native player via web ...

Comment: @KBoek so,there is any way to get the play duration from the native player via web ?

Comment: @RohitJindal Not that I know of, as the web and the player are two totally separate apps. But I'm not iOS or Android expert, you should probably tag your question different (remove the PHP and JavaScript tags, and add iOS/Android tags)

Comment: @KBoek Its not related to (iOS/Android)..its related to web.

Comment: @RohitJindal No, it's related to the mobile OS, as you use the mobile's native player, not a web-based player.

Comment: @KBoek I agree with you. Bt i am not able to find the exact solution of the problem. If you have contacts please help me out or share this post in your profile.

Comment: @KBoek u found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in the comments, it isn't possible to determine the exact streaming time.

Different clients have different behavior with how they handle streams.  Consider the case where a browser client may pre-buffer data.  If the user goes to a page and the browser begins downloading audio data, the server will think that the client is listening to the stream when in fact the data is just sitting in memory.  When the user does start playing the audio, say 1 minute later, the server now believes they have already been listening for a minute.  When the user goes to a new page, the connection to the server is dropped, stopping audio at the same time as disconnection.

In other cases, media players can actually be paused mid-stream where they buffer the data for several seconds before disconnecting.

The best you could do is use client-side analytics, but this isn't possible in all circumstances since you are not always in control over the client, and not all clients would be capable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that on server (wowza) side. Well you can, but data won't be accurate, because of buffering and how HTTP streaming protocols work in general.

However, you can still aggregate those data using some sort of javascript on client side.

You have to listen for player events like - play, pause, stop, even seek. Most web players have callbacks to track those events. Then collect data and send them to your db for storage.

Answer (score -1):

To get duration of the stream, you have to develop a custom module. There is an event called  onMediaStreamDestroy, using IMediaStream object you can get the duration.
   public class MyMediaStreamListener implements IMediaStreamNotify
   {
       @Override
       public void onMediaStreamDestroy(IMediaStream stream)
       {
       stream.length(); // this is used to get the length of the video in seconds
       }
   }

Comment: @Manikandan..i can't understand..can u explain more?

Comment: @Manikandan This is not a solution for many reasons. Most importantly, due to the nature of HTTP streaming, the server side stream length can be 30-40 seconds off compared to client side.

Comment: @KBoek HTTP is a stateless protocol..so we can't track the user state when control goes to client side.